How to replace a table in pg Admin through Jupyter Notebook?
How to replace a table in pg Admin through Jupyter Notebook?
I used this script Class_yelp.to_postgis("class_yelp4", engine), it runs, but when I want to restart the kernel or run the all script from the beginning, here comes me the message, that "ValueError: Table 'class_yelp4' already exists."
It is for me useful when we change one column in Jupyter ntb, and wanted than to replace threw Jupyter ntb. How can I fix it?
I tried these varieties: Class_yelp.to_postgis("class_yelp4", engine, if exist = replace/append). Replace runs, but then PG admin shows no data in the table. Append put the data at the end of the existing table, so than I have doubled more rows.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
